# For loop printing evenly divided number given a range

Tags: loops, for-loop, numbers, range

Write a program that accepts a start number from the user and an end number. For each number in that range, it will print all the numbers that divides it evenly (division such that there are 0 remainders).

I've been able to only get the first number in the range, but it won't print the proceeding and final numbers. The example input was just: 85 89. The output should look like this:

85 is evenly divisible by 1 5 17 85

86 is evenly divisible by 1 2 43 86

87 is evenly divisible by 1 3 29 87

88 is evenly divisible by 1 2 4 11 22 44 88

89 is evenly divisible by 1 89

```
import java.util.*;
public class NumberRange { 
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num1;
    int num2;
    num1 = in.nextInt();
    num2 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print(num1 + " is evenly divisible by ");
    for(num2 = 1; num2 <= num1; num2 ++)
      {
         if (num1 % num2 == 0)
         {
            System.out.print(num2 + " ");
         }
      }
 }
}
```

Comment: What is your input?

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs exhibit this invariant: `num1 <= num2`. So rather than discarding the `num2` input with `for (num2 = 1; num2 <= num1; num2 ++)`, you want an outer loop of:

```
for (int n = num1; n <= num2; n++)
```

which either calls a helper function (that contains a loop), or at least calls a nested loop running from `1` .. `n`, testing remainders. Your teacher will be impressed if you put the inner loop in an appropriately named helper function. Hint: you'll need to declare yet another variable for that inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1;
        int num2;
        num1 = in.nextInt();
        num2 = in.nextInt();

        for(int i = num1; i <= num2; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(i + " is evenly divisible by ");
            for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                if (i % j == 0)
                {
                        System.out.print(j + " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```